# Selecting exactly $2$ men given at least one woman is selected.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A committee of four is to be chosen from a group of four men and five women. What is the probability that the committee contains exactly two men given that at least one woman is chosen?

I have tried to break the problem down.
I created a new problem with one less woman, $1$ less on the committee and one less person in total.

So I did $\frac{\binom42\cdot\binom41 }{\binom83}$
Which is equal to $\frac37$

But it's $\frac{12}{25}$!!!(not factorial)

Okey doke I solved it.

I took the probability of exactly two men and divided it by the probability of at least one woman!!! (exactly two men means exactly two women)

(4choose2 * 5choose2 / 9choose4)/(125/126)

Comment: Please include your efforts.

Comment: Also, what is the source of the problem?

Comment: As far as I have understood the problem, two particular men are have to be selected for sure ,thus making up two cases : one with apart from the two already considered 1 W, 1 M and the other with 2W.( M-men.W-women)

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453052/selecting-exactly-2-men-given-at-least-one-woman-is-selected/4453247#4453247).  I am going to try to get other MathSE reviewers to examine the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ = (exactly two men)
Let $W$ = (at least one woman)

It is easy to see that $P(M\cap W) = P(2M,2W)  
= \dfrac{\binom42\binom52}{\binom94}$

and P(W) $=  \dfrac{\binom94-\binom44}{\binom94}$

Hence P(exactly two men | at least one woman) = $=\dfrac{P(M\cap W)}{P(W)} = \dfrac{\binom42\binom52}{\binom94- \binom44}=  \boxed{\dfrac{12}{25}}$

Comment: @user2661923: Hi, I see that J Moravitz and Lulu have already given explanations.

Answer (score 0):

@user...1923 If I don't misunderstood  the problem,  I don't think so. As "...the committee contains **exactly two men**..." Thus, there are only 1 committee spot left to fill, from the 4 remaining women.

According to your arguments, it happens the case in which all 4 people of committee are female.

Comment: It seems to me that 2 cases have to be considered as I have explained in my comment above.

Comment: +1 to your answer.  You are right.  My initial comment was hasty and (as it turns out) wrong.  So, your dispute of my comment is perfectly accurate.  I thought that the correct computation was $$\frac{\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{3}{7}.$$  Subsequently, I convinced myself that this is wrong, and that the right answer is $$\frac{12}{25}.$$  Actually, this seems counter-intuitive to me.  I am still unsure what was wrong with my original thinking.  Since the comment was wrong, I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to the answer/response of OGFandEGF, who determined that I originally made a hasty (and inaccurate) comment, following the original posting.  See the comment that I left following OGFandEGF's answer.

Actually, this got me wondering what was wrong with my initial thinking.  First, I will independently verify that the answer of $~\displaystyle \frac{12}{25}~$ is correct.

Then, I will **attempt** to diagnose the flaw in my original thinking, which matches the thinking of the OP (i.e. original poster).

Initially, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{4} = 126$ equally likely ways that the $(4)$ committee members could have been selected from the $9$ people.  When you are given that there is at least one woman on the committee, you exclude exactly $(1)$ one of the $(126)$ selection possibilities, because only $(1)$ of the $(126)$ ways of forming the committee involved selecting all $(4)$ men to be on the committee.

Then, of the $(125)$ remaining, equally likely ways that the committee might have been formed, exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{5}{2} = 60~$ of these selection possibilities involved having exactly $(2)$ men on the committee.

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{60}{126 - 1}.$$

---

My original thinking was as follows:

Assume that the women are named Alice, Betty, Cathy, Diane, and Edwina.  You know that there is at least one woman on the committee.  The probability of the committee having exactly $2$ men on it is not affected by which woman is known to be on the committee.

Therefore, without loss of generality, you can assume that Alice is on the committee.  Then, there are an additional $3$ committee slots to fill from the remaining $8$ people.

Exactly as the OP did, I then (incorrectly) reasoned that the probability of having exactly $2$ men on the committee
is

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{8}{3}} = \frac{24}{56}. \tag1 $$

To tell you the truth, I grappled with this problem for over $(2)$ hours.  In my opinion, Probability Theory absolutely requires intuition.  I see nothing counter-intuitive in the analysis that resulted in the computation in (1) above, which **I have proven to myself must be wrong.**

---

Finally, I went back to basics, and constructed the following chart:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{# of women} & \text{# of ways} & \text{# ways with Alice} \\
  \hline                       
  4 & \displaystyle\binom{5}{4} \times \binom{4}{0} = 5 & \displaystyle\binom{4}{3} \times \binom{4}{0} = 4 \\
  \hline 
  3 & \displaystyle\binom{5}{3} \times \binom{4}{1} = 40 & \displaystyle\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} = 24 \\
  \hline 
  \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{\displaystyle\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} = 60} & \color{red}{\displaystyle\binom{4}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} = 24} \\
  \hline  
  1 & \displaystyle\binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} = 20 & \displaystyle\binom{4}{0} \times \binom{4}{3} = 4 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

I know that:

- The numbers in the 2nd and 3rd columns have been accurately computed.
- The $\color{red}{\text{third row : # of women} ~= 2~}$ represents the *satisfactory* cases.
- The $(125)$ ways that the committee could be formed, as represented in the 2nd column are equally likely.
- The relative weights given to the various possible number of women, as represented by the 2nd column, must therefore be accurate.  
  Therefore, these weights must be in the proportion of
  $[5::40::\color{red}{60}::20].$
- Therefore, the relative weights given to the various women, as represented by the 3rd column, **can not be accurate**. 
  Therefore, the following relative weights must be wrong:
  $[4::24::\color{red}{24}::4].$

---

Suppose that the problem had been phrased differently.  Suppose, instead of specifying that there was at least $(1)$ woman on the committee, it was specified that Alice was on the committee.

It seems to me, that under the alternative specification, the relative weights given in the $3$rd column would be appropriate, and that therefore, the probability would be

$$\frac{24}{56}. \tag2 $$

As I see it, there are two possibilities, with respect to the alternate problem, where Alice is specified as being on the committee.

- Either I am wrong, and the computation of $~\displaystyle \frac{24}{56}~$ is wrong.
- Or, there is some significant difference between specifying that there is at least one woman on the committee, and specifying that Alice is on the committee.
  I suspect that the 2nd possibility above pertains.  This is curious.  If you know that there is a woman on the committee, you know that that woman has a name.  Why should revealing that name alter the computation?

I am going to flag various other MathSE reviewers, to see if they can provide an intuitive explanation here.

Comment: Consider one man and two women, us picking two people. What is probability man is selected given at least one woman (which here tells us nothing)?  Given alice specifically was selected?  Convince yourself these are different.  I'll elaborate after morning commute

Comment: @JMoravitz Very nice.  I got it.  The probability changes from $(2/3)$ to $(1/2)$.  Unfortunately, as far as intuition stretching, the lesson seems to be that specifying a name for one of the chosen people alters the computation.  Not that different from part 1 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452990/combinations-a-deck-with-separate-hands-and-players/4453013#4453013), where I assumed, without loss of generality, that the person's hand contained $4$ 9's and a $10$.  Curious intuition stretching.

Comment: This "paradox" is a variant of the usual Boy/Girl issue.  Specifying that the eldest child is a girl is different from saying that one of the children is a girl.

Comment: "*...specifying a name for one of the chosen people...*" So, we are given that there is at least one woman selected and you say that we can find *her* name, and that name is equally likely to be any of the women and so without loss of generality might as well have been Alice.  If there was one person, yes that is fine.  There being one woman we can indeed ask *her* name.  In the event that there were multiple women selected however, how do you decide which of the potentially many you ask the name of?  It is possible to have gotten an answer back different than Alice despite Alice being present

Comment: It is for that reason that the event "we got at least (*potentially more than*) one woman and the only woman we asked their name was named Alice" and "we got alice" are different events.  There are more outcomes in the second event than in the first.

Comment: @JMoravitz Here, I am confused.  If there are $n$ women, $k$ of which have been selected, and the first woman says "My name is Alice", then there are $$ \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ possibilities for the other women.  If instead, I ask: "Are any of you $k$ women named Alice", and they say "Yes, one of us is", then there are **still** $$\binom{n}{k} - \binom{n-1}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ possibilities.  Which two *events* are you focusing on?